# Heroku: Migration issues when pulling production database to testing and running rake db:migrate

Tags: activerecord, heroku

I have 3 instances of my rails app on heroku (test, stage and production). When I want to test an issue that is happening with real users' data, I would like to heroku db:pull --app production and then heroku db:push --app test. The problem is that at this point heroku rake db:migrate --app test throws an error because the columns the migration is trying to create have already been created.

My understanding is that heroku db:push pushes data into an existing database schema and rather than literally pushing the entire database (schema included). This means that the schema we are pushing to may be more advanced than the migrations table we are pushing since this migrations table will be missing migration records that have not run on the database we pulled from but have obviously run on the database we are pushing to.

My first question is, am I correct in my understanding of how this works? My second question is how do I fix this so that I can pull production data, stick it in testing and run migrations without receiving this error. Ideally, I would want to copy the production database and stick it in test and then migrate it fully since if I could do this I wouldn't have to worry about the existing schema on test. Is there a way to do this?

If not, is there a way to fake that migrations have already run by populating the new migrations table with records for each migration that has already run on my test database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, db:push pushes the local schema and data. You can push your local DB into an empty DB  on Heorku, this is how I put sites live - when you run it you see it creating the schema then pushing the data in.

I work like this - Test environment on Heroku same code as live - ie. a branch of master (ie what's live and pushed to test). Pull DB from Live. Fix on my local system. Push to test and run migrations. Test release against DB on Heroku. When I'm happy merge test code into master and then deploy and run migrations. Rinse and Repeat for future bugs. The production DB should never have a more advanced schema version that test. You can always check this out by looking in the schema_migrations table - this is how Rails knows what migrations have run so far, so you can compare this to db/migrations files.

Comment: It looks like heroku db:pull just sticks new data into my existing schema though so when that happens running rake db:migrate on local produces the following error. When I look in the database, I see that it is behind on migrations and has tables that are created in migrations that haven't yet run. Is there a way just to pull the entire db to local including the schema and overwrite everything I have on local? SQLite3::SQLException: table "user_roles" already exists

Comment: yes, pull will do that. If you've run migrations locally that say create tables then pulling from live won't erase your local db first - so your user_roles table will already exist locally but your schema_migrations table won't think it's run so let's you run after you pull -then bam, error. You want to make sure your local DB is COMPLETELY empty rake via db:reset before you pull.